# Error in chapter 17 in beginner level: Recording and playing back data

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I need someone to help me. I am following the tutorial that is in the main ROS, but in the chapter: Recording and playing back data, when I run the recorded data I get this error:

turtlebot turtlebot-F200CA @: ~ / $ rosbag bagfiles -a record
/ opt / ros / hydro / lib / rosbag / record: symbol lookup error: /opt/ros/hydro/lib/librosbag.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3ros7console5printEPNS0_10FilterBaseEPN7log4cxx6LoggerENS0_6levels5LevelEPKciS9_S9_z

Someone who can tell me or help to resolve this. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197342/error-in-chapter-17-in-beginner-level:-recording-and-playing-back-data/) by [Ruben](https://answers.ros.org/users/20796/ruben/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems to me like it can't find some stuff from ros console?

Are you missing some ros dependencies?
-> http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep

Maybe also try roswtf: http://wiki.ros.org/roswtf

---

Originally posted by [AReimann](https://answers.ros.org/users/20356/areimann/) with karma: 88 on 2014-11-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1